# Linear Algebra, proving

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I know that the distance of v and u equal to the distance of AB and AC, but how should I prove that by using number. I believe it is not that easy as well. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Why did you assume that the triangle is right? There’s nothing in the problem statement to suggest that.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $|u.v|^2=||u||^2||v||^2 \cos ^2(A)$

Thus $$||u||^2||v||^2-|u.v|^2 $$

$$=||u||^2||v||^2 \sin ^2(A)$$

Substitute in the formula for the area and you are done .